# Are indeces useful when using them in combination of an INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
Orders

OrdersPromotions

Promotions
```

Most of my queries are of this kind:

```
SELECT `promotions`.* FROM `promotions` INNER JOIN `orders_promotions` ON `promotions`.`id` = `orders_promotions`.`promotions_id` WHERE `orders_promotions`.`orders_id` = 3 AND `promotions`.`code` = 'my_promotion_code'
```

So, I never fetch promotions directly, but also within the scope of an order. An order won't have many promotions. I am wondering if it would be useful to place an INDEX in the code column of promotion, knowing that when doing the INNER JOIN actually the results after the INNER JOIN are not many, and so, it would be ok to go through all them finding the promotion which code is the given.

Would an index make sense in my previous query, knowing that just this query:

```
SELECT `promotions`.* FROM `promotions` INNER JOIN `orders_promotions` ON `promotions`.`id` = `orders_promotions`.`promotions_id` WHERE `orders_promotions`.`orders_id` = 3
```

Would return no more than 20 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost always use an index on any fields you are going to use for joins, sorts, grouping, or filtering in where clauses. I would say ALWAYS, but there could be exceptions to the rule (like if you had a very heavy write load on a table that was very infrequently used for reads where indexes would be useful).

Comment: My confusion is the following: If I do ``SELECT * FROM PROMOTIONS WHERE `code` = 'whatever'`` I see the advantage of putting an index in `code`. However, since I will never do that kind of queries, but I will do an INNER JOIN with another table that will decrease the number of final results, would that still be useful?

Comment: I mean, the ``where code = 'xxx'`` is applied right after the INNER JOIN set has been found. And that set is going to be really small (20 rows MAX). Would the index still makes sense?

Comment: @HommerSmith Yes. In fact your assumption that the join is calculated first is probably wrong, in that, in most cases, the filter on `orders_promotion` would likely be applied first. You can always look at the `EXPLAIN` results for a query to see what is really happening. At any rate, you shouldn't assume your tables are only going to by X size.  Good database design would have you using indexes in all cases above that I mentioned.